# Arithmatic operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class money
{
    int rs;  
    int p; 

    public:

    void setdata (int x , int y) 

     {rs=x; p=y;}

    void show() 

   { cout  <<rs  <<"."  <<p; }  

    money operator += (int a)  {

    money temp;
    temp.rs=rs+a.rs;
    temp.p=p+a.p;   
    return (temp);  
    }
};



  int main() {

    money c1,c2;

    c1.setdata(8,2);

    c2=c1.operator+=(4);

    c2.show();

}
```

> Can someone tell me why the operator += overloading doesn't work?
>
> My desiring output is 12.2 but the output i got is 16.2 .
>
> I am sending 4 as argument and i want this argument is added in r (ruppee) 
>     part

Comment: `+=` is supposed to modify `this` and return a reference to `this`

Comment: I don't see `operator+=` invoked anywhere..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: `c2=c1.operator(4);` does this even compile??

Comment: [no it does not compile](https://ideone.com/BrQDBK)

Comment: please make sure the code matches the problem you describe. See also [mcve]

Comment: i just edited my code please take a look again.

Comment: @user463035818  i just want to return temp into the c2 object

Comment: `temp.p=p;`  you are not adding anything here. And if you fix that your operator is still doing the wrong thing. What you implemented is an `operator+`

Comment: @user463035818  i just want to add the r part

Comment: @user463035818 sir this is my assignment questions and its always throwing wrong output

Comment: @user463035818  13.5 + 1.5 = 15.00 what just i want to show sir

Comment: i still dont get it, but probably this ` temp.rs=rs+rs;` is not what you want but rather `temp.rs = rs + a.rs;`. Currently you dont use the `a` parameter at all

Comment: @user463035818 i have just edited my code.. and it still throws a error about temp.rs = rs + a.rs;

Comment: why?? now it wont compile anymore. My mistake was to overlook that the parameter to the operator is an `int` not a `money`. If you want to add that `int` to your money then you need to add it...

Comment: @user463035818 but how sir??

Comment: `rs` is an `int`, `a` is an `int`. How do you add two `int`s?

Comment: @user463035818 affter adding it show 20.2 as an ouput it stills wrong.

Comment: hum this question is a train wreck. Here is the correct implementation: `money& operator+=(int a) { rs += a; return *this; }` and you use it as `c1 += 4;`

Comment: @user463035818   thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class money
{
    int rs;  
    int p; 

    public:

    void setdata (int x , int y) 

     {rs=x; p=y;}

    void show() 

   { cout  <<rs  <<"."  <<p; }  

   money& operator+=(int a) 
   { rs += a; return *this; }
};



  int main() {

    money c1,c2;

    c1.setdata(4,2);

     c2=c1+=(4);               //c2=c1.operator+=(4);

    c2.show();

}
```

Comment: `c2=c1+=(4);` is correct, but it completely misses the point of having a `operator+=` instead of a `operator+`. `operator+=` modifies the left hand side and its return can be assigned to `c2` but typically you dont. Just use `c1+=4; c1.show();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use constructor correctly.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Example
{
public:
    int x;
    Example(int a)
    {
        x=a;
    }
    Example operator+(Example obj)
    {
        Example ans(0);
        ans=x+obj.x;
        return ans;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example a(10),b(20);
    Example ans=a+b;
    cout<<ans.x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).